# Error count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable with laravel return view

Tags: arrays, laravel

I get this error saying that it is not an accountant but I do not understand why this happens to me, if someone can give me a help I would appreciate it

**code controller**

```
$errors = 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.';

        return view('albaranes/index',[
            "errors"=>$errors,
        ]);
```

**View, show errors**

```
<div class="alert alert-danger ">
                    @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif
        </div>
```

Comment: `$errors` is reserved in Laravel, its tied to validation.

Comment: `$errors` is a string here, but you're using it as an object (I'm guessing an ErrorBag?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be aware that you've passed a string to your view, but you're using errors as an object, where Qirel has mentioned, it's used by laravel. You can override it and this should `fix` it....

```
    <div class="alert alert-danger ">
        @if (isset($errors))
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @if(!is_string($errors))
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    @else
                        <li>{{ $errors }}</li>
                    @endif
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
```